# Flask app runs locally but on Heroku Cannot render template?

Tags: heroku, flask

For some reason my Flask app runs fine on my local computer but when deployed to heroku I receive a render template error.

procfile: web: gunicorn app:app

Basic file structure:

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtZXh.png)

---

[Heroku Log Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tIV9.png)

```
2019-03-20T16:42:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-03-20T16:42:58.002302+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=headphones.herokuapp.com request_id=856e996e-9716-4688-8474-49e1102938ae fwd="96.35.158.2" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=455 protocol=https
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999048+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-03-20 16:42:57,996] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999062+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999064+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999065+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999069+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999071+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999073+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999074+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999076+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999082+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999084+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999086+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999088+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999089+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999091+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 55, in home
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999092+00:00 app[web.1]: return render_template("index.html")
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999094+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999096+00:00 app[web.1]: return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999097+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999099+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999101+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999102+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999104+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999105+00:00 app[web.1]: template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999107+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999108+00:00 app[web.1]: source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999110+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 58, in get_source
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999111+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999113+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 86, in _get_source_fast
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999114+00:00 app[web.1]: raise TemplateNotFound(template)
2019-03-20T16:42:57.999120+00:00 app[web.1]: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
2019-03-20T16:42:58.000010+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.213.200 - - [20/Mar/2019:16:42:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
2019-03-20T16:42:58.180976+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.213.200 - - [20/Mar/2019:16:42:58 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://headphones.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
2019-03-20T16:42:58.183263+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=headphones.herokuapp.com request_id=3bb6ecd2-778e-499e-b0e6-72913e8c4a08 fwd="96.35.158.2" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=385 protocol=https
```

Comment: Check if Procfile has uppercase P.

Comment: Please copy/paste your heroku error into question - it will be searchable and copyable

Comment: ...as text, not as an image. After pasting you can select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to indent it by four spaces so SO will treat it as a block of code.

Comment: Procfile has upper case. 

Will paste error log as text once I run the heroku tail log here soon. 

Thank you for the quick responses and apologies for the poor formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the files weren't all sent to Heroku.

If you're deploying with git, make sure that all files are being shipped to the slug.

In your place, I'd try inspecting the contents of the slug by doing `heroku run bash -a name-of-your-app` and check if all files are where you'd expect them to be.

Answer (score 0):

@elias Well I wish I tried that first. Not sure what it ending up being but I just rebuilt the entire app one part at time deploying to heroku as I added in parts to see what may have been causing the issue. Unfortunately I never did, however the app works now.

So yeah something was not being pushed up when I tried uploading the app as whole.

Thank you to everyone for the assistance on my first post!